# Stylize select option to be functional also without JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to stylize select option in way that select will be fully functional even if JS is turned off.

1. If user will NOT HAVE JS turned on - then `<SELECT>` will be used
2. If user will HAVE JS turned on - then **JS** ADDED `<DIV>` will be used

Is this good approach or is there some better how to do it?

I am building whole web in way, that it will be usable also if JS is turned off.

My HTML code:

```
<h3>Filtre</h3>
        <section class="section" id="section-filters">
            <div class="add-item__form-data">
                <div class="add-item__input-wrapper">
                    <select name="filter_brand" placeholder="Značka" class="add-item__select<?= highlightSelectIfEmpty('filter_error', 'filter_brand') ?>" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected class="add-item__select-main">Značka</option>
                        <option value="Samsung" <?= markSelectedAfterResend('filter_brand', 'Samsung') ?>>Samsung</option>
                        <option value="Nokia" <?= markSelectedAfterResend('filter_brand', 'Nokia') ?>>Nokia</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="add-item__input-wrapper">
                    <select name="filter_model" placeholder="Model" class="add-item__select<?= highlightSelectIfEmpty('filter_error', 'filter_model') ?>" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected class="add-item__select-main">Model</option>
                        <option value="Samsung S20" <?= markSelectedAfterResend('filter_model', 'Samsung S20') ?>>Samsung S20</option>
                        <option value="Samsung S30" <?= markSelectedAfterResend('filter_model', 'Samsung S30') ?>>Samsung S30</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="add-item__input-wrapper">
                    <select name="filter_os" placeholder="Operačný systém" class="add-item__select<?= highlightSelectIfEmpty('filter_error', 'filter_os') ?>" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected class="add-item__select-main">Operačný systém</option>
                        <option value="Android" <?= markSelectedAfterResend('filter_os', 'Android') ?>>Android</option>
                        <option value="iOS" <?= markSelectedAfterResend('filter_os', 'iOS') ?>>iOS</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="add-item__input-wrapper">
                    <select name="filter_memory" placeholder="Pamäť" class="add-item__select<?= highlightSelectIfEmpty('filter_error', 'filter_memory') ?>" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected class="add-item__select-main">Pamäť</option>
                        <option value="20GB" <?= markSelectedAfterResend('filter_memory', '20GB') ?>>20GB</option>
                        <option value="60GB" <?= markSelectedAfterResend('filter_memory', '60GB') ?>>60GB</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="add-item__input-wrapper">
                    <select name="filter_color" placeholder="Farba" class="add-item__select<?= highlightSelectIfEmpty('filter_error', 'filter_color', 'yes') ?>" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected class="add-item__select-main">Farba</option>
                        <option value="Biela" <?= markSelectedAfterResend('filter_color', 'Biela') ?>>Biela</option>
                        <option value="Čierna" <?= markSelectedAfterResend('filter_color', 'Čierna') ?>>Čierna</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

My JS code:

```
   /* SELECT BOX */

    var select = $('.add-item__select').hide(); // Hide original select options

    // Replace each select by div
    select.each(function(){
        var selectVal = $(this).find('.add-item__select-main').text();
            newDropdownDiv = $('<div class="add-item__select">' + selectVal + '<i class="arrow down"></i></div>')
                .insertAfter($(this))
                .css({paddingLeft: '0.3em', cursor: 'pointer'});
    });


    // Add new div with options after click on select
    $('.add-item__select').on('click', function() {

        var currentNewDropdown = $(this).next(),
            currentSelect = $(this).prev();

        // Check if new div dropdown already exists
        if (!currentNewDropdown.hasClass('add-item__custom-select-box')) {
            var newDropdown = $('<div/>') // create new div element
                .addClass('add-item__custom-select-box') // with class NewDropdown
                .insertAfter($(this)); // and append it to page
        }

        // If select was already clicked on, then do not create new dropdown list
        if (!currentSelect.hasClass('counted')) {

            // Check each option value and attach it to new dropdown as div
            currentSelect.find('option').each(function(index, element){
                var option = $(this); // this is the option from the original select
                    currentNewDropdown = $(this).parent().next();

                // If option is disabled do not append it to new dropdown list
                if (!option.prop('disabled')) {
                    var newOption = $('<div/>') // create new div element
                        .addClass('add-item__custom-select-box-items') // with class NewDropdown-item
                        .html(option.html()) // copy content from original option
                        .data('value', option.val()) // copy value from original option
                        .appendTo(newDropdown); // append it to the new dropdown
                }
            })
            // Show new dropdown options after click on select
            currentNewDropdown = $(this).next();
            currentNewDropdown.show();
            currentSelect.addClass('counted');

        } else {
            // Remove new dropdown list
            currentNewDropdown.remove();
            currentSelect.removeClass('counted');
        }

    });

    // Add value of clicked element to original option
    $('.add-item__input-wrapper').on('mousedown','.add-item__custom-select-box-items', function() {

        var clickedOption = $(this),
            clickedOptionVal = clickedOption.text(), // set original select's value
            select = $(this).parent().prev(),
            newDropdown = $(this).parent();

        select.val(clickedOptionVal);
        newDropdown.remove();
    });

    // Hide select box after focus out
    select.on('focusout', function() {
        var newDropdown = $(this).next(),
            select = $(this);
        newDropdown.remove();
        select.removeClass('counted');
    });
```

Comment: If JS was turned off, none of your code would be run. Are you asking if there's an alternative without JS?

Comment: "*your opinion about my approach*" - your approach is to attempt to run some js when js is turned off?  You could use server-side to generate the HTML and css (`:hover`) to show a dropdown which had checkboxes (styled so actual boxes checkboxes are hidden) - then you could have styled "select" without js.

Comment: *"your opinion about my approach"* - not that "opinion" questions are explicitly off topic for SO.  You could possibly change your question to "how can I style a select without js" then ask how to do it and include what you've attempted ("here's what I've tried using js").

Comment: @freedomn-m I already modify my question, it was little bit confusing.

Comment: Things seem mostly okay. What's the content of `markSelectedAfterResend`?

Comment: Save Selected Items After Page Reload
  

 function markSelectedAfterResend($session_name, $value) {

  if ( isset($_SESSION[$session_name]) && ($_SESSION[$session_name] == $value) ) {
   unset($_SESSION[$session_name]);
   return 'selected';
  }

 }